# Removing quotation marks in json file python

Tags: python, json

I accidentally double encoded a json file.
Now i need to get rid of the quotation marks around its body.
How can i do it ?

The Json I have looks like this:

```
'"{"created_at":"2022-06-03T13:00:52.000000Z","created_by":"foo","event":"foo"}"'
```

And I need to look it like this:

```
{"customerId":"foo","mobile":"foo","projectId":"foo"}
```

Comment: That's not even double-encoded; the quotes around the JSON strings would all be escaped, like `"{\"created_at": \"2022-06...\", ...}"`.

Comment: As is, though, you may just be able to use `bad_json = bad_json.strip(")`.